# Get the tenant id of an registred app in azure AD using microsoft graph powershell

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I know how to get the tenant id of Azure AD. But i have registred an APP in Azure AD using microsoft graph powershell and i want to obtain  tenant id of this registred app using microsoft graph powershell. I tried to get it using the variable i used to create the app registration:

```
$APP = New-MgApplication   -displayName $AppName `
                           -RequiredResourceAccess @{ ResourceAppId = $GraphResourceId; ResourceAccess = @($resourceAccess) } `
                           -SignInAudience $SignInAudience `
                           -PublicClient @{ RedirectUris = $URL }
```

If i use the variable $App and try to get a property called tenantid, there is nth called like this. `$App | Select *` did not show any tenantid aswell.

Anyone know how to read the tenantid of this registred azure app using microsoft graph powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph API doesn't provide any information about tenant for registered application, so you cannot get tenant id directly.

The registered application is created under the same tenant that the user or application is signed in to.

You can read organization data

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.DirectoryManagement

$org = Get-MgOrganization
```

`$org.id` is the tenant ID.

Documentation:

[Organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/organization?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thank you. Got it. I needed some time to understand that the Tenant-Id of the Apps under one Azure AD is always the same. Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

You can get the tenant id, by following below commands , ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-to-find-tenant#find-tenant-id-with-powershell

Connect-AzAccount

Get-AzTenant

To list all To the tenants for your account, you can use:
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2020-01-01
ref doc - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list

If you want to see the tenant ID associated with an app registration, you can do so through the portal under Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > the app registration > Overview. I don't believe it's possible to get this data via Powershell since Powershell requires both Tenant ID and Application ID to query the application information.

See the doc more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/find-ids-and-domain-names

Hope this helps

Thanks